# How to ignore query string on firebase hosting CDN?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

Hi i have an URL in my firebase hosting, let's call it `/success.html`

The use case, user make an http request to my http cloud function instance, upon success i will redirect the request to the `/success.html` with query string. here is example: `success.html/id=?foo`

The problem is I want to serve `/success.html` through firebase CDN, but firebase hosting CDN treat each query string unique cache key. So `success.html/id=?foo` and `success.html/id=?bar` wont hit the same cache key.

Can I omit the query string from the cache key? So `success.html/id=?any-id-here` will return resource cached from `/success.html`

Thank you

Comment: Why would you want requests with different queries to hit all the same cache? If the parameters change, then they should reach the backend.


Also, your query string isn't correctly formatted, it should be "success.html?id=foo" instead of "success.html/id=?foo"

Comment: The idea is, I don't want to install any template engine on my cloud functions to minimize dependency, so I just redirect it to static HTML page with query string on it. I send the ID generated by server by redirecting request to static page with query string on the URL, then on client side I parse the query string and show it on the screen like "Your ID is: xxxx".

Thank you for pointing out the query string mistake.

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, a template engine is actually what you want to use instead of redirecting to the static file as the CDN takes the [query string in consideration for caching](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache#when_is_cached_content_served).

Comment: I "solved" the issue, I hosted my static page on Netlify, they don't cache the query strings. Template engine will inflate my function size and slower compared to CDN. But thank you for your response.